# Is it possible to somehow merge these two lines into a single one using some ES6 syntax?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In my array of objects called `weekTimes`, I'm looking for an object whose `date` property is equal to `this.mon`. If an object is found, I want its `hours` property value to fill out a DOM `input` element referred to as `this.monTime`.

Then I need to do the same thing for each day of the week. I feel there must be a more elegant way to shorten all of this than what I have so far (see below) but I can't find one. Any suggestion would be welcome.

```
var temp;
temp = weekTimes.find(x => x.date === this.mon);
this.monTime = temp.hours;

temp = weekTimes.find(x => x.date === this.tue);
this.tueTime = temp.hours;

...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this with an array of property (day) names:

```
["mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri"].forEach(day => {
    const temp = weekTimes.find(x => x.date === this[day]);
    if (temp) this[day + "Time"] = temp.hours;
});
```

Or, you could turn the tables, and just iterate `weekTimes` once:

```
weekTimes.forEach(x => {
    if (["mon","tue","wed","thu","fri"].includes(x.date)) {
        this[x.date + "Time"] = x.hours;
    }
});
```

If it is certain that `x.date` will always be a day of interest, then you can even skip that `includes` test:

```
weekTimes.forEach(x => this[x.date + "Time"] = x.hours);
```

#### Input element?

You write in your question that `this.monTime` refers to an input element. But to set the value of an input element you need to set its `value` property. Is `monTime` is a setter function that does just that? If not, you should probably do `this.monTime.value = ....`, with the extra `.value`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider a more functional approach and avoid relying on external scope to perform your update: (I am assuming from your example that that is the case)

Here's a function taking a date to look for in a list of time objects. If an object is found, it executes given callback:

```
/**
 * Finds in given list of times, a time which date property is set to given date.
 * When a time is found, pass it as an argument to given callback.
 * When no time is found, callback is not executed
 * @param date {string}
 * @param times {time[]}
 * @param cb {function}
 */
const whenCurrentDay = (date, times, cb) => {
  const found = times.find(time => time.date === date);
  found && cb(found);
};
```

You would then use it as follows:

```
whenCurrentDay('mon', weekTimes, time => console.log(`do something with ${time.hours}`));
whenCurrentDay('tue', weekTimes, time => console.log(`do something with ${time.hours}`));
whenCurrentDay('wed', weekTimes, time => console.log(`do something with ${time.hours}`));
whenCurrentDay('thu', weekTimes, time => console.log(`do something with ${time.hours}`));
whenCurrentDay('fri', weekTimes, time => console.log(`do something with ${time.hours}`));
whenCurrentDay('sat', weekTimes, time => console.log(`do something with ${time.hours}`));
whenCurrentDay('sun', weekTimes, time => console.log(`do something with ${time.hours}`));
```

I'd admit that this is slightly more verbose indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the below functional approach

```
    for(day in ['mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat','sun']){
      this[day + 'Time'] = weekTimes.find(x => x.date === this[day])
                                    .map(x => x.hours);
}
```